# How can I refresh my cshtml file from a process in my MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postback, page-refresh

I've developed a process which validates a screen and if the validation fails I display a dialog box with the error and show the offending field in Red. The code which updates the fields only works after a post back or refresh. The code before I display the dialog box is

```
string error = string.Empty;
if (response.ErrorMessages.First().Error.Contains("You are already active on stage"))
    error = response.ErrorMessages.First().Error + ". To stop this stage and continue, please select Continue";
else
    error = response.ErrorMessages.First().Error;
return PartialView(Constants.CloseDialogRenderWorkflow, error);
```

How can I refresh my cshtml file so that the Red fields appear and then show my dialog box?

Comment: To do what you are trying to do, you really need to do it client side with a bit of jquery and Html. Why dont you use the in-built functionality with MVC and place constraints on your model and use something like the validationSummary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested, many validations can be done using `MVC framework` builtin support, by the aid of attributes and using a typed model. A very good tutorial that shows this can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model).

Comment: Absolutely. And you can create your own custom annotations/validators to use in your models if what is provided doesn't do what you need.